# How do I fix fatal error: Can't form a Character from an empty String

Tags: swift

I'm new to Swift and it took me 1h to debug, but I still don't know why it failed.

This is a question from leetcode: to reverse a string:

input: "hello"

output: "olleh"

And there is my code:

```
import Foundation
class Solution {
    func reverseString(_ s: String) -> String {
        // initialize a new null string
        var answer = ""
        // get the length of the input string
        var lengthOfString = s.characters.count
        // add the character into the new string
        for nums in 0...(lengthOfString-1){
            var index = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: lengthOfString)
            answer.append(s[index])
            lengthOfString-=1
        }
        return answer
    }
}

let a = Solution()
let b = a.reverseString("hello")
print(b)
```

here is the picture of my error:

[image]

Comment: solved, thank you, I just ignored the length of that input string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue was in this block:

```
for nums in 0...(lengthOfString-1){
    var index = s.index(s.startIndex, offsetBy: lengthOfString)
    answer.append(s[index])
    lengthOfString-=1
}
```

1. should use `0..<lengthOfString` for the range.
2. you are changing the value of lengthOfString which is a very bad way.

Here's a sample to reverse the string you want to do:

```
extension String {

    subscript (i: Int) -> Character {
        return self[characters.index(startIndex, offsetBy: i)]
    }

    subscript (i: Int) -> String {
        return String(self[i] as Character)
    }

    func reverse() -> String {

        let count = characters.count
        if count == 0 { return "" }

        var result = ""
        for i in 0..<count {
            result = self[i] + result
        }

        return result

    }

}

let s = "hello"
s.reverse() // print: olleh
```

Comment: No, it is the problem that offset cross the boundary, but still appreciate you answer

Comment: your suggestion is right, I will use ..< later in my code

Comment: Check the updated answer, I added a sample code for you.

Comment: OMG, smart answer, which is better than mine, hhhhha